# react-responsive: cannot pass props to children of a Responsive component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using the common use case indicated in the ReadMe:

```
const Desktop = props => (
  <Responsive {...props} minWidth={1680} maxWidth={2560} />
)
const LaptopL = props => (
  <Responsive {...props} minWidth={1440} maxWidth={1679} />
)
...
```

and I have a prop (bottleState) that I am trying to pass to specific components inside the Responsive component (eg Desktop):

```
const WineHeader = ({ bottleState }) => (
  <HeaderCard>
    <Desktop>
      <WineBox />
      <WineBackgroundBox />
      <VineyardBackgroundBox />
      <WineInfoContainer>
        <LeftContainer>
          <WineTypeBox bottleState={bottleState} />
          <WineTitleBox bottleState={bottleState} />
          <WineDescriptionBox bottleState={bottleState} />
        </LeftContainer>
        <WineProperties />
      </WineInfoContainer>
    </Desktop>

    <LaptopL>
      <WineBox />
      <WineBackgroundBox />
      <VineyardBackgroundBox />
      <WineInfoContainer>
        <LeftContainer>
          <WineTypeBox />
          <WineTitleBox />
          <WineDescriptionBox />
        </LeftContainer>
        <WineProperties />
      </WineInfoContainer>
    </LaptopL>
     ...
  </HeaderCard>
)

WineHeader.propTypes = Object.freeze({
  bottleState: PropTypes.object, //eslint-disable-line
})

export default WineHeader
```

When logging the bottleState prop in one of the above child components in which I am trying to access it - it is not available (the log returns undefined) :

```
const WineTypeBox = ({ bottleState }) => (
  <WineTypeStyle>{console.log(bottleState)}</WineTypeStyle>
)

> undefined  ---- WineTypeBox.jsx?a13c:36
```

and when I simply remove the Responsive component, I can access the bottleState prop as expected:

```
const WineHeader = ({ bottleState }) => (
  <HeaderCard>
    <WineBox />
    <WineBackgroundBox />
    <VineyardBackgroundBox />
    <WineInfoContainer>
      <LeftContainer>
        <WineTypeBox bottleState={bottleState} />
        <WineTitleBox bottleState={bottleState} />
        <WineDescriptionBox bottleState={bottleState} />
      </LeftContainer>
      <WineProperties />
    </WineInfoContainer> 
    ...
  </HeaderCard>
)
```

returns the bottleState object when logged to the console:

```
{wineCollection: "Classics", wineType: "Semi Sweet Red", bottleName: "Khvanchkara", bottleImage: Array(1), bottleNoteText: "<p>test</p>", …}
bottleImage: ["http://localhost/uploads/bottle.png"]
bottleName: "Khvanchkara"
bottleNoteText: "<p>test</p>"
temperatureHigh: null
vintage: null
volume: null
wineCollection: "Classics"
wineType: "Semi Sweet Red"
__proto__: Object ---- WineTypeBox.jsx?a13c:36
```

Any ideas why this is the case? I have tried defining the desktop function inside the WineHeader functional component, because that is the function where I am pulling off the bottleState prop from this.props but this doesn't change the behaviour; when throwing a debugger before the return statement of the Desktop component, I can clearly see the bottleState prop being passed in, I do not even need it to be passed in as I am directly passing it into other components nested further down the DOM tree without any issue when the Desktop Component is not wrapping them, but the fact that my other components that need to access this prop are nested inside the Desktop component is causing the props to be blocked for some reason. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Corey

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use the react-responsive's context to pass props?

Comment: @tgerr So that was my first approach - I tried implementing the ReadMe example and kept getting the error: 

_'Uncaught ReferenceError: ResponsiveContext is not defined'_

Comment: I tried to put the code snippets here but they seemingly do not format well in comments, any idea why ResponsiveContext is not defined - I am importing it like so: `import Responsive, { Context as ResponsiveContext } from 'react-responsive'`

Comment: Also, shouldn't it work without the context API?

Comment: Can you test: 1. adding props to the second `<WineTypeBox />`. 2. Adding a `<Default ...>` wrapper, and 3. Passing props with `WineHeader = props =>` and `<WineTypeBox {...props} />` thanks

Comment: Because the most likely problem is that Desktop isn't receiving the bottleState to pass down the props to its child components. That's because bottlestate is destructured in `({ bottleState })` with `{}`. The other possibility is: your device is rendering <Laptop />. The third is having multiple components inside of the desktop wrapper. And 4th is how react-responsive is dealing with children and context.

Comment: wow, it was simply the idiotic mistake of trying to access the props on the wrong screen size. Both your suggestion of `<WineTypeBox {...props} />` and my initial approach of destructuring `bottleState` and passing it like so: `<WineTypeBox {bottleState={bottleState} /> ` work just fine! @tgrrr - Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I wouldn't feel bad about it: sometimes it's just helpful to have a second set of eyes on the problem. I've posted my detailed answer below @coreycosman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it's possible that you're expecting to look at the `<Desktop>` and actually looking at the `<LaptopL>` screen:

```
const WineHeader = ({ bottleState }) => (
  <HeaderCard>
    <Desktop>
      ...
      <WineTypeBox bottleState={bottleState} />
      <WineTitleBox bottleState={bottleState} />
      <WineDescriptionBox bottleState={bottleState} />
      ...
    </Desktop>

    <LaptopL>
      ...
      <WineTypeBox /> // <- pass props here
      <WineTitleBox /> // <- pass props here
      <WineDescriptionBox /> // <- pass props here
      ...
    </LaptopL>
  </HeaderCard>
)
```

Which you mentioned fixed it in the comments above. Kudos!

**For reference**:

It's also good practice with react-responsive to add a `<Default ...>` wrapper.

This can happen with other libraries, and require a different fix.

Eg. The initial destructure of props into `({ bottleState })` might mean that `react-responsive` can't access `props` in order to pass them onto their child components. When this happens with external libraries, it can be fixed in several ways:

1. Pass the props with the spread syntax

   const WineHeader = props => (
     ...
       
         ...
         
         ...
       
   )

*OR*

```
const WineHeader = ({bottleState, foo, bar}) => (
  ...
    <Desktop>
      ...
      <WineTypeBox {...{bottleState, foo, bar}} />
      ...
    </Desktop>
)
```

2. Pass a single component, or wrap the libraries JSX inner components because the library can't handle multiple child components

   const WineHeader = ({bottleState}) => (
     
       
         
         ...

*OR*

```
const WineHeader = ({bottleState}) => (
  <HeaderCard>
    <Desktop>
      <Fragment>
        <WineTitleBox bottleState={bottleState} />
        <WineTitleBox bottleState={bottleState} />
        ...
      </Fragment>
    </Desktop>
```

3. Passing props using [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)